# How Can I show only selected div elements based on a certain condition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So this is the snippet of my code, the aim here is to either hide or show the h4 element based on my condition.

```
 <h4 ng-hide="data_startupcosts.note == ' '">THE COST OF STARTING THIS VENTURE</h4>
 <div ng-repeat="data_startupcosts in data.startupcosts track by $index">
 {{data_startupcosts.note}}
 <ul ng-repeat="data_startupcosts_lists in data_startupcosts.list track by $index">
 <li>
```

I used ng-hide with an expression but no luck...... any suggestions?????

Comment: Your condition is `data_startupcosts.note == ' '`? Have you made sure the condition is correct?

Comment: Create plunker  or filddle with your code

Comment: Also, you use the `data_startupcosts` outside the `ng-repeat`, so it won't exist there

Comment: Are you sure that you want to check that `note` is one space and not empty ?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `data_startupcosts` outside your `ng-repeat`, so that variable won't exist in there. Instead use it inside your `ng-repeat` scope:

```
<div ng-repeat="data_startupcosts in data.startupcosts track by $index">
    <h4 ng-hide="data_startupcosts.note == ' '">THE COST OF STARTING THIS VENTURE</h4>
    {{ data_startupcosts.note }}
    <ul ng-repeat="data_startupcosts_lists in data_startupcosts.list track by $index">
        <li>..</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or, if you really want it **outside** the div, use `ng-repeat-start`:

```
<h4 ng-repeat-start="data_startupcosts in data.startupcosts track by $index" 
    ng-hide="data_startupcosts.note == ' '">THE COST OF STARTING THIS VENTURE</h4>
<div ng-repeat-end>
    {{ data_startupcosts.note }}
    <ul ng-repeat="data_startupcosts_lists in data_startupcosts.list track by $index">
        <li>..</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also make sure your condition is correct, you are comparing with a single space, but maybe there isn't any space? (`data_startupcosts.note == ''`)

Comment: He probably wants to check !data_startupcosts.note